# Using "@use" rule to import partials into a main sass file returns undefined errors when i`m trying to use variables or mixins

Tags: sass

I have a problem with using `@use` rule to bring partials into the main scss file. The current setting I have:
- using node.js installed on my local computer,
- chocolatey,
- dart sass v 1.25.0.

This is the file structure that I have:
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWFcC.jpg)

**The issue**
I'm using `@use` to bring all partials into `core.scss`. I've written some basic mixins in `mixins/main.scss`, like the example below:

```
@mixin font-use {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem !important;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.4 !important;
}
```

When I'm calling the mixin `font-use` into `_structure.scss` and save, it returns an undefined mixin error.
I've searched on the internet to see if there is a problem with `@use` since is fairly new or I'm doing something wrong.

PS: if I change `@use` rule with `@import`, there are no errors after the compilation is done.